# OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain

Tags: bug, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid

I'm asking this here because I suspect it applies to multiple sites.

When I try to login to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ for the first time using my Google OpenID, I get the following error from Google:

```
OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain:
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/
```

A search turned up only one possibly-related question on another site:
[Error while trying to sign up for this SE site using Google OpenID](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/error-while-trying-to-sign-up-for-this-se-site-using-google-openid)